# There has been a critical error on this website – on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: php, wordpress

I was trying to add the plugin FiboSearch to my store on WordPress using NgInx Ubuntu 22.04, but when making the searches, I always got the message saying that there has been a critical error on this website. can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please add the full error output to your question. It should have been sent to the admin email and/or added to the debug.log

Comment: I added and checked in the log-file. We might missing "mbstring". Thanks for your suggest

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to upvote my comment. You might also want to add the error output from the log to your question, just in case other people are searching for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added and checked in the log-file. We might missing "mbstring". So, I just install 'sudo apt-get install php-mbstring'. Now it work ok